# two graphs in one plot matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I want to plot two data (x1,y1)=(x,y) which x and y determine some points in space and (xx1,yy1)=(12,12) in the same plot in Matlab. I used below code but there is an error and it doesn't wor. Could anyone help?

```
  h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10,12,12,'.r', 'MarkerSize', 15);
```

The complete code is as below.. I want to show a red big dot at the center of the video:

```
clear all
close all
l=25;
v=0.05;
dt=1;
r=1;
rr=25;
noise=(2.*pi).*.05;
nn=100;
set(gcf, 'doublebuffer', 'on', 'Color', 'k');
set(gca, 'Visible', 'off');
axis([0 l 0 l])
axis('square')
hold on
vidObj = VideoWriter('vicchemo1.avi');
open(vidObj);
x=rand(nn,1).*l;  %first possition
```

Comment: You can only use the `MarkerSize` attribute at the end of the `plot` call, so that means the `MarkerSize` of all points will have to be the same for one `plot` call.  Therefore, split it up into multiple plot calls as you see in the answers below.

Comment: I can not. I added the complete code, I wanna make a video @rayryeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just below `h = plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10);` on line 46. Add the following code:

```
xc = xlim/2;
yc = ylim/2;
plot(xc(2), yc(2), '.r', 'MarkerSize', 15);
```

Comment: I can not use this method in my code, please see the added code in question

Comment: The code seems to work fine for me. What exactly is your issue? Do you get an error? If so, what does the error message say?

Comment: It works but doesn't show red big point at the center of video

Comment: sorry?!  I didn't understand

Comment: Check my updated answer ;) Btw, what does the code simulate? It looks interesting.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I accidentally posted half a comment ^^

Comment: You can probably change xc and yc to something nicer. It will fail if x and y -limits do not start at 0. Your call :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood your question properly or not. Below lines of code plot the data on same figure:

```
 plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10)
 hold
 plot(12,12,'.r', 'MarkerSize', 15)
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
hold on
plot(x, y, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 10)
plot(12,12,'.r', 'MarkerSize', 15)
hold off
```